# JqueryMobile Getting details about Item Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a three level hierarchy.The first two levels are Collapsible whereas the final one is a list.When i click the list I have to pass the data about the list item clicked and the name of its parent and its grand parent.
I am unable to get the data about the item clicked .The js code is (read below the code also)

```
       var commodity;
       var variety;
       var grade;
       var content;

       var jsons ='[{"Turmeric":[{"Bulb":["Grade 2","Grade 1"]},{"Finger":["Grade
                                                                               1"]}]}]';



       var data = $.parseJSON(jsons);
       var nextId = 0;
       $.each(data, function(key, value){
           $.each(value, function(key, value){       //Runs for each commodity

                commodity = key;
                var data1 = value;

                 $(document).on("pageinit", function() {
                 nextId++;

                 content = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed-icon='arrow-r' 

         and data-expanded-icon='arrow-d' id='setk'><h3> " + commodity + "</h3><p>";

                $.each(data1, function(key, value){
                    $.each(value, function(key, value){
                      variety = key;

                content = content + "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed-
  icon='arrow-r' and data-expanded-icon='arrow-d' id='setk'><h3> " + variety + "</h3>

   <p>"+

                 '<ul data-role="listview" id="noth">';

                  for(var i=0, len=value.length; i < len; i++){
                            grade = value[i];
                            invis = commodity+variety+grade;
                            content=content+'<li><a href="ext.html" id=commodity 
             onclick=senddata(?????) rel="external">'+grade+'</a></li>';
                                    }


                 content = content + '</ul>';




                 content = content + "</p></div>";
                           });
                                  });

                content = content +"</p></div>";

                  $("#set").append( content ).collapsibleset('refresh');    
                 $("#set").enhanceWithin();
                   });   

          });             
              });


    function senddata(data) {
     localStorage["1"] = data;
      alert(data);
        }
```

Please Not:if i give the parameter of grade or variety or commodity to onclick method ,it sends the last updated value of these which is not correct

Comment: Tell me is there a good reason why you are using rel="external" in your next page link?

Comment: If i don't then on clicking the next page is not loaded because the error  
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///..../www/ext.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."
occurs

Comment: Let me guess you are testing using Chrome?  And doing it without proper web server?

Comment: Yes , Using chrome and without any server.

Comment: Then this is your problem. Chrome is extremely bad used for testing without a web server. My advise you should use Firefox or Chrome pair with WAMP/XAAMP. This error will not happen when you finally put your application into production. And jQurey Mobile works better if AJAX is used for page loading.  Not to mention, I can show you several solutions to your problem, but only if you stop using rel="external".

Answer (score 0):

A few points to help you along:

First, you are clearly re-using variables that you need not touch:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
       $.each(value, function(key, value){
```

The inner $.each() replaces whatever values you have in **key** and **value**.

Second, you do not need to bind the pageinit event in a loop; it will fire multiple times. Also the pageinit is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah , i am reusing the variable but what can be the remedy ? I mean how can i track the list item that I have clicked

Comment: There are millions of other variables you can use in the inner loop; k and v for example. That's something you want to fix by all means.